# Install Firebase Extension via CLI with `--params` flag does not bypass interactive prompts

Tags: firebase, firebase-cli, firebase-extensions

Following the [official docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/install-extensions?platform=cli#view-details) under the `Bypass the interactive terminal prompts for parameter values during installation` section, I have provided the extension configs with a `.env` file and passing it through the `--params` flag. However, the installation command still prompts:

```
extensions: You will be charged around $0.01/month for the Firebase resources required by this extension (even if it is not used). Additionally, using this extension will contribute to your project's overall usage level of Firebase services. However, you'll only be charged for usage that exceeds Firebase's free tier for those services.

See pricing examples: https://cloud.google.com/functions/pricing#pricing_examples
See the FAQ: https://firebase.google.com/support/faq/#extensions-pricing


? Do you wish to continue?
```

and

```
extensions: Resize Images will be granted the following access to project quaza-staging-f5446
- Storage Admin (Full control of GCS resources.)
? Would you like to continue?
```

Am I missing something here?

P.S. the install went well besides the prompts so I assume there is nothing wrong with how I setup my `.env` file.